# Discord Plays Embedded Videos That Don't Allow Embedding, How?

Tags: html, youtube, discord

I'm trying to create a website using angularJS and I want to show youtube videos. So I have setup the means to do that, but some videos don't allow embedding and say "Video Unavailable" only when you press *Play*. However, when I post the exact same links into discord through Chrome, they do play. Looking through the DOM tree, I can see Discord embeds those same videos using an iframe and Discord *CAN* play them. I've had a look at the *YouTube API* and can't seem to see anything on it, anyone know how Discord does this?

This video allows embedding: https://www.youtube.com/embed/zoSJ3bNGPp0.
While this one doesn't: https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfJYHfrOGgQ